# Laravel 5.2 muliple file field upload

Tags: php, file, laravel, upload

Hi I have stumbled across a problem while messing around with Laravel 5.2 I dont know if the problem is specific for 5.2 or occurs in other versions of the framework.

Basically what I'm trying to do is upload multiple files trough a single html file input field this is what I have.

The view:

```
<form method="post" action="nieuw" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="images" multiple>
</form>
```

The request file:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'images' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
    ];
}
```

And last but not least the controller:

```
public function store(Requests\EventRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->file('images'));
}
```

Now when uploading multiple files trough the inpute field this is what the dump shows.

```
UploadedFile {#30 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "anotherone.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -size: 64112
  -error: 0
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "phpm57pCe"
  basename: "phpm57pCe"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpm57pCe"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/phpm57pCe"
  aTime: 2016-02-25 23:46:57
  mTime: 2016-02-25 23:46:57
  cTime: 2016-02-25 23:46:57
  inode: 1443315
  size: 64112
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 900
  group: 900
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

It just seems to catch the last file u submitted trough the upload field. Note that the request validator does work at this point you can only upload the set mime types but its the request that fails to show all the files.

What I have figured out on my own is that setting the html input field into an array like this

`<form method="post" action="nieuw" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" multiple>
</form>`

fixes the problem on the controller end making the dump look like this

```
array:2 [▼
 0 => UploadedFile {#30 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "test - kopie.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 64112
    -error: 0
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpj3V7H1"
    basename: "phpj3V7H1"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpj3V7H1"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpj3V7H1"
    aTime: 2016-02-25 23:52:21
    mTime: 2016-02-25 23:52:21
    cTime: 2016-02-25 23:52:21
    inode: 1443314
    size: 64112
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 900
    group: 900
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  1 => UploadedFile {#31 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "anotherone - kopie.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 4721735
    -error: 0
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpWSm5U9"
    basename: "phpWSm5U9"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpWSm5U9"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpWSm5U9"
    aTime: 2016-02-25 23:52:21
    mTime: 2016-02-25 23:52:21
    cTime: 2016-02-25 23:52:21
    inode: 1443315
    size: 4721735
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 900
    group: 900
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
```

However trough this method validation has completely gone out the window by doing so and i have tried changing my validator into:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'images.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
    ];
}
```

And into

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'images.0' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
    ];
}
```

Both of them hopelessly failed. I hope some of you can help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no validation for `array` of iamges what you can do is

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'images' => 'required'
]);
$files = $request->file('images');
foreach ($files as $file){
   $validator->after(function($validator) use ($file) {
      //make your valdiation
   });
}
if ($validator->fails()) {
   //validation didn't pass
}
```

The other way

```
$files = $request->file('images');
foreach ($files as $file){
   $input = ['upload' => $files[$i]];
   $rules = ['upload' => 'image|max:15500'];
   $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);
   if($validator->fails()){
    //validation didn't pass
    break;
   }
}
```

A third way is to create your own [Validation rule](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-where-to-add-custom-validation-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can validate file array like any input array in **Laravel 5.2**. This feature is new in Laravel 5.2. You can do like following:

```
$input_data = $request->all();

$validator = Validator::make(
    $input_data, [
    'image_file.*' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp|max:20000'
    ],[
        'image_file.*.required' => 'Please upload an image',
        'image_file.*.mimes' => 'Only jpeg,png and bmp images are allowed',
        'image_file.*.max' => 'Sorry! Maximum allowed size for an image is 20MB',
    ]
);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // Validation error.. 
}
```

Note, you can also use `$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);` inside a controller.